# How to make a timer more efficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am quite new to coding and i am wondering how to make it more efficient. I am running it on a raspberry pi which will have other tasks so i want this to be as easy to run as possible.  The code will use a magnetic sensor to record passes made by a magnet mounted on a wheel and from there determine the speed of the outside diameter of the wheel.  It would be useful to implement something that takes the five last speed outputs and gives sort of an average but only if it does not affect the complexity of the code much. Would be really greatful for any help!

```
from gpiozero import Button
import time
global t0
t0 = time.clock()
raduis = 300
button = Button (21)
from signal import pause

def calculate_speed(radius):
    global t0
    t1 = time.clock
    interval = t1 - t0
    speed = radius/interval
    print (speed, 'mm/sek')

y = True
while y == True:
    button.when_pressed = calculate_speed(radius)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    #used to prevent one pass of the magnet from recording many passes
```

Comment: It might be just me, but this kind of questions may be better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I disagree- it seems that OP is asking how to proceed with coding the loop and averaging, not how to improve the current code.

Comment: as it currently stands your code doesn’t look at the interval since the last pass, since you never adjust t0.

Answer (score 3):

You should store five last speed outputs in an array (list) and then you can calculate the average speed

```
speed_records = []
def calculate_speed(radius):
    global t0
    t1 = time.clock
    interval = t1 - t0
    speed = radius/interval
    print (speed, 'mm/sek')
    speed_records.append(speed) # Adds one speed record to the list
    if len(speed_records) >= 5: # checks if there are 5 five records available
        last_five_records = speed_records[-5:] # Seperates five last records
        average = sum(last_five_records) / 5
        print('Average Speed:',average) # Prints out the average
    if len(speed_records) > 10: # Free Up some memory
        speed_records = list(set(speed_records) - set(speed_records[:5])) #removes the first five records
```

Comment: Do you keep adding to the list forever till all memory is consumed?

Comment: @MarkSetchell no but you're right I should remove some of the old records which aren't used anymore. I'll edit

Answer (score 2):

The following code uses modular arithmetic to iterate through a single list, adding and overwriting values, and printing the averaged speed. Adjust `iterations` to control how many passes to average over.

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import time

radius = 300
button = Button (21)

iterations = 5
speeds = [0] * iterations
speed_idx = 0

def calculate_speed(radius):
    global speeds, speed_idx
    t1 = time.time()
    speeds[speed_idx] = radius / (t1- t0)
    print (sum(speeds) / iterations, 'mm/sek')
    speed_idx += 1
    speed_idx %= iterations

t0 = time.time()
while True:
    button.when_pressed = calculate_speed(radius)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    t0 = time.time()
```

Note this takes 5 measurements to "ramp up" in a sense. If you want- you could add an if statement to avoid printing out the first 4 recordings.

Additionally, if you wanted a smoother measurement of speeds, it occurred to me that you could use a single value to hold the sum of the speeds of the last N passes, and each time subtract off the average (assuming N sums), and add the new speed. It would a few extra passes to stabilize, but afterwards it should smooth the reported speeds a bit.